# CLMM Output interpretation from R Ordinal

Tags: r, logistic, ordered-logit

**Problem description**
question is at the end:

I am testing to see what factors are responsible for vegetation change over a large landscape over a period of 100 years. The response variable is an ordinal measure of vegetation change describing how different the vegetation is in terms of its successional state. The response can be 0 (no change), 1 (a little bit of change), 2 (moderate change) or 3 (Maximum change). 
Predictors:

I have a model with a random factor (Blockshed: watersheds to control for spatial autocorrelation), an ordered factor (tsf: time since fire)and two continuous variables (Z.elev: standardized elevation; Z.solar : standardized solar insolation).

I am using the CLMM procedure in R:Ordinal package.

Because there are three possible levels of tsf (short, medium, very long), the model tests both linear (L) and quadratic (Q) terms for the variable (n-1 models, if the TSF had 4 levels, it would also test Cubic) . These two models are indicated in the output by TSF.L and TSF.Q. As you will see both are significant, so I would assume I would choose the model with the lowest p-value, or if they are identical (as is the case here), choose the simplest (L) model.

This is the code to run the model:

```
library(ordinal)
MGall32.clmm <- clmm(chgdir ~ Z.solar + tsf + Z.elev + (1 | blockshed), 
                     data = MG09, Hess = TRUE,
                     control = clmm.control(method = c("nlminb")))
```

The following is the output from the model:

[image: model output]

Question: 
what is CLMM doing in the Linear vs Quadratic models? The response variable is an ordered factor with values of 0, 1, 2
I have read the CLMM package description, and it does not specify what is going on under the hood.

Created using this code:

```
vegtrans$tsf <- with(vegtrans, factor(tsf, levels=c('S','M','XL'), 
                                    ordered=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't separate *models* for the linear and quadratic term for `tsf`; the results you show are for *one single* model containing *both* terms. What the results are suggesting is that you need to have the quadratic term rather than just represent/approximate `tsf` as a linear function only.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that begins to make more sense. Can you tell me how I can visualize this either graphically or mathematically?

Comment: I can visualize how a linear term affects the output . i.e. as Time Since Fire (TSF) gets longer, the vegetation change (chgdir) tends to be more positive (grasslands become forests).
But how do I interpret the inclusion of the quadratic term with a negative slope? Is this just dampening the effect of the Linear term?

Comment: I haven't really gotten my head round what all the coefs mean, but think of a line that is `y = x + x^2`, a quadratic relationship. That is how to interpret those coefs. A simple way to visualise this would be to predict from the model for the three TSF categories whilst holding the other variables at their mean or reference levels. Then you can visualise the relationships between y and TSF conditional upon the other covariates values.

Comment: That makes sense, but do you mind looking at the following link: this describes some CLMM output using a predictor as a factor, and then as an ordered factor. It is only when it is an ordered factor that these extra terms come in. In this attached example's case it includes Linear, quadratic, cubic.... all the way to 7th power terms. In the attached example's case, only the Linear term has a p < .05

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q2/018412.html